# Analog signals in profibus

Tags: profibus

I've read that in Profibus, both analog and digital signals can be transmitted on the same wire. I'm curious how this happens and wasn't able to find an answer on google. Could someone please explain or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a decent picture of a typical bus system: -

[image]

The system consists of a master unit and many slaves. The "wire" which connects everything up carries the digital data from all the slaves to the master. If the slave happens to be a monitor for some temperature sensor, it will digitize the temperature and at some point the master will interrogate that slave and collect that data.

So, in short, only digital signals are sent over the wire but, some of those digital signals represent analogue values.

I stole the picture from [here](http://www.icpdas.com/root/product/solutions/industrial_communication/fieldbus/profibus/profibus_intro.html). Below is another picture: -

[image]

Answer (score -2):

http://www.bluejeanscable.com/articles/digitalanalog.htm

Digital and analog signals both cannot send by a same wire at a time.

Comment: You can simultaneously send an audio baseband analogue signal with the superimposition of a digital signal provided the digital signal's bandwidth does not encroach at the baseband where the audio is. This can be done and has been done - for instance... a regular internet connection to the home carries baseband telephony audio but has a load of other stuff for the internet stacked above it at higher frequencies.